# Maven JVM terminated unexpectedly with exit code 0 on weblogic deploy

Tags: maven, hudson, weblogic

I have written pom.xml for auto deployment process between hudson and deployment servers.

The script which i return its working perfectly i can see the application in web logic server. The application has been deployed in the web logic server. No issues that.

All the remaining task is also very well working in the servers but the build is failing as **failed** by saying the below error in hudson

```
[ServerConnectionImpl.close():332] : Closing DM connection   
[ServerConnectionImpl.close():352] : Unregistered all listeners  
[ServerConnectionImpl.closeJMX():372] : Closed JMX connection  
[ServerConnectionImpl.closeJMX():384] : Closed Runtime JMX connection  
[ServerConnectionImpl.closeJMX():396] : Closed Edit JMX connection  
**ERROR: Maven JVM terminated unexpectedly with exit code 0**  
Sending e-mails to: test@gmail.com  
Finished: FAILURE
```

I don't know why this is happening in maven.

Here is my maven opts set in Hudson server.

```
Maven_OPTS : -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Comment: Maybe check whether all plugins have the most recent version? What plugins do you have?

Comment: We can't possibly help you unless you tell us what plugin you have configured that is logging those ServierConnectionImpl messages. You aren't using maven-exec-plugin to run code of your own, are you?

Comment: Thanks for your response. @bmargulies: I didnt use maven-exec-plugin . I used weblogic-maven-plugin for deployment process.

Comment: Look like a bug in that.

Comment: Can you run it with -X so we have more details ?

Comment: Inlcuding the plugin configuration in your pom and relevant versions is probably also helpful here.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very old question yet I just ran into this weird issue and this costed me 3 hours in debugging the Jenkins Job configurations and Jenkins plugins.
This answer is to help others if they encounter the same.

Root cause:  I got to know that one of a developer in my team has used                `system.exit(0);` 
in his java code so actual problem was in code not with jenkins job.

Solution: Remove

```
system.exit(0);
```

Comment: Aswsome .. I was facing the exact issue .. voting you up

Answer (score 0):

Without more to go on, I'm going to speculate you are getting hit by [this issue with the weblogic maven plugin](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MWEBLOGIC-18). In order to resolve that problem, make sure you are running the latest version of the plugin. If that doesn't resolve it then I think you should try adding the following to your pom's plugin configuration:

```
<noExit>true</noExit>
<continueOnFailure>true</continueOnFailure>
```

The first line stops weblogic from exiting and the second line tells the deployer to continue. You could try just adding each one individually.

If none of the above helps, then there is another System.exit() somewhere in the code path. You might need to hook up a debugger.